# SwiftUI button space on different devices

Tags: uibutton, swiftui

I have a swiftUI button defined at the very bottom of my app as follows:

```
VStack {
   Rectangle().foregroundColor(.yellow)
   Button(action: {
     withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
        self.viewModel.resetGame()
     }
   }, label: {
      Text("NEW GAME")
      .fontWeight(.bold)
      .font(.system(size: 22))
      .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
      .padding()
      .background(Color.orange)
      .cornerRadius(40)
      .foregroundColor(.white)
      .padding(10)
      .overlay(
         RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40)
            .stroke(Color.orange, lineWidth: 5)
       )
   })
}
```

On the iPhone 11 the button looks good:

[image]

On the iPhone 8 plus, on the other side, it doesn't have any padding at the bottom, resulting "collapsed" into the bottom of the screen:

[image]

I tried to apply `.padding(.bottom)` to the whole button but the result is that the area for the button overflows the button itself:

[image]

This way a user could actually click on the white space outside the button and inside the blue area and still trigger its effect. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please provide extended code example and let us see what is on top of the button. Why does it appear on the bottom? Is it in a VStack with Spacer on top or something else?

Comment: @DI.dev I don't think it matters much, but I put it inside a VStack. I updated my code so you can reproduce the example I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.offset(y: -20)` modifier to the button, It will not increase the button area but move the button upwards.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I also just tried to add a Spacer() after the button definition and that worked too.